# Can't connect to actioncable socket and no error and rejection - what can I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

Some users are unable to connect to my socket and I have no idea why. I don't see any errors but I do see that they never actually connect. What can be the cause of this and what should I do? I am using Rails actioncable.

I see this is called and the room id is present.

```
window.subscription_channel = consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: "RoomChannel",room: $("[data-room-id]").data("room-id")},
{
  connected: this._connected.bind(this),
  disconnected: this._disconnected.bind(this),
  received: this._received.bind(this),
  rejected: this._rejected.bind(this)
}
);
```

And once it connects I set a variable

```
_connected() {
  window.socket_has_connected_to_room = true
  console.log("connected to room via action cable socket")
}
```

I do a check after 15 seconds and see the `window.socket_has_connected_to_room` variable is not true and can see the subscription_channel is present and can verify window.subscription_channel.consumer.connection.disconnected is true. What can I do in this scenario?

Comment: Also if `window.subscription_channel.consumer.connection.disconnected` is false, does that mean they are connected? Not sure how I can check that they have connected which is why I set the `window.socket_has_connected_to_room` variable but im nervous that I can't trust the join method or that variable being set correctly.

Comment: Maybe you're using a port for actioncable that their internet is blocking for some reason? Or if the default websocket or secure websocket link it's usually open though.    You could ask them to connect to your wss:// link directly and tell them if their browser is showing any errors...

Comment: Is there a way I can test that programmatically without needing to contact them? One strange thing I see is that it's almost always Chrome and Windows 7 or 10.

Comment: My goal would be to reproduce the problem on a local device or device(s).  Then you can start fiddling. Conected/disconnected are not good to measure as there are a kazillion still-connecting states.  For me my JS app was using actioncable and my production server anycable.  But that's for myself testing (all users) not just some.

Comment: Yea I use a mac and can't reproduce the issue. Just crazy to me there is no error and no one else talking about it. Im not doing anything crazy.